# Mousemove effect animate not found

Tags: jquery, mousemove, mouseenter, mouseleave

Is there any way to make the effect smoother when we entered the container.

The idea is that the list of icons or numbers must be relative to the center then it occurred put it this way, but I can not make softer positions without losing the mousemove is a plugin I found on the web if you have any suggestions would be great;)

http://jsfiddle.net/rvalverde/zw6pJ/11/

Comment: Please post the relevant code to your application, not just a dump

Answer (score 0):

I added a css3 transition on your li anchors. You can adjust the timing. Depends on legacy browser support as well to use this.

```
-o-transition: all .4s ease;
-ms-transition: all .4s ease;
-moz-transition: all .4s ease;
-webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
transition: all .4s ease;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zw6pJ/12/

Comment: I think this is the effect you're looking for. Not completely sure ;}

Comment: But when I leave the mouseleave is very strong, I tried several ways and nothing, any ideas?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. When it resets and goes back to the start correct?